# jQuery validation plugin not validating on form$.validate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a page that has been using the jQuery validation plugin successfully to validate several text fields.  There are several submit buttons on the page, and I have configured the validator as follows:

```
_validator = $("#ftsEditTripForm").validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function() {}
});
```

I register the following click event handler for all the submit buttons on the page:

```
function clickHandler(jqEvent) {
    var action = jqEvent.target.id;
    if (action !== "cancel") {
        _form$.validate();
        if (_validator.numberOfInvalids() === 0) {
            submitForm(action);
        }
    } else {
        confirmCancel(action);
    }
}
function submitForm(action) {
    $(".flowEvent").attr("name", "_eventId_" + action);
    if (action === "submit" ) {
        $("input[name=status]").val("S");
    } else {
        $("input[name=status]").val("D");
    }
    _form$[0].submit();
}
```

This has been working fine.  Validation isn't done until the user clicks one of the submit buttons and, if that button is the Cancel button, the user is asked to confirm they want to lose any changes they've made on the page before the page is actually submitted.  So we're stopping page submission if the user clicks the Cancel button and then clicks the No button, saying they don't want to continue with the cancel operation.

Now I've added tabs to a navigation bar, and I need to do the same kind of thing if the user clicks on a tab other than the tab for the page she's on now.  The tabs are implemented as divs, and I've defined the following click event handler for those divs:

```
function tabClickHandler(jqEvent) {
    var target = jqEvent.target;
    while ( ! $(target).hasClass("navTab")) {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    var tabNumber = target.dataset.tabnumber;
    _form$.validate();
    if (_validator.numberOfInvalids() === 0) {
        $("input[name=tabNumber]").val(tabNumber);
        submitForm("navbar");
    }
}
```

My problem is that _validator.numberOfInvalids() always returns 0 when I click on a tab.  I've put a breakpoint in my validation code, and it isn't called when I click on a tab.  As a result, the page is always submitted, even if there are validation errors.

I've tried a number of things -- various values for the validation plugin's onsubmit and submitHandler options, changing the tab divs to buttons -- without success.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I have to get this working one way or another, and I'd like to keep using the validation plugin.

Thanks for reading this far.

Thom

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
_form$.validate();
```

I've never seen variables named like this (`_form$`)

You should know that the `.validate()` method is only used for initializing the plugin on the form.

```
function clickHandler(jqEvent) {
    var action = jqEvent.target.id;
    if (action !== "cancel") {
        _form$.validate();

    ....
```

So if you don't initialize it until after you click the button, then you're not going to have any validation at all.

Typically, `.validate()` is only called once within the DOM ready event handler and the click event is captured is automatically.   You cannot call `.validate()` more than once since all subsequent instances are ignored.

Since you have a `cancel` button you want to ignore, you can use the `.rules('remove')` method to effectively cancel validation if the cancel button is pressed.  Something like this...

```
$('#myCancelButton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('remove');  // remove all rules
    });
    // something to do on cancel
    confirmCancel(action);
});
```